Print Report Page
I'm trying to print a report in Visual Studio Windows Form.
The report should have a logo and intestation for each page and the page orientation should be landscape.
The body of report is displayed in a RichTextBox.
I tried but I don't understand how to modify the page orientation and page break.
Can you help me?
This is the code:
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    string IMAGE = "";
    sqlite.Open();  //Initiate connection to the db
    string stm = "SELECT VALORE FROM IMPOSTAZIONI WHERE IMPOSTAZIONE = 'LOGO';";
    using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, sqlite);
    using SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        IMAGE = (string)rdr["VALORE"];
    }
    sqlite.Close();

    Image bgFront = Image.FromFile(@"Immagini\" + IMAGE);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bgFront, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Report Movimenti in Uscita non Pagati", new Font("Courier New", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(160, 40));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox1.Text, new Font("Courier New", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 150));
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
}

Buttoin1 is the button that I use to print the report.
If I print the report I see:

But I'd like a different page orientation and I don't know if at the end of the pages at pages 2 the logo and intestation repeted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.landscapeangle?view=net-8.0 For landscape you need to rotate it

to add page break maybe use this ev.HasMorePages = false; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs?view=net-8.0

Add this line of code to your program and you can see changes of the print page orientation when you execute it.
printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings. Landscape = true;

